# New markup style in ribbon

Tags: ribbon

I'm able to add a markup style to ribbon by creating a new class like `div.ms-rteElement-mkg-div { -ms-name: "New markup"; }`

This works well, but what if I want to add a new class, and maybe insert a H4-tag within a span?
Like this: 
`<span class="myclass grid_4"><h4>This was inserted automagically</h4>This is some content</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the Reusable Content feature in SharePoint Server 2010. Reusable Content is a list with HTML snippets that can be inserted to Site Pages.

Comment: The user must be able to insert and edit both the title and the content, is this still possible with reusable content?

Comment: You can use any kind of HTML snippet as reusable comment, and yes it can all be edited

Comment: Yeah I just misunderstood the option when creating the reusable content. Thought I could choose the ability to update it globally or not. This works perfectly, now I just need to find a way to deploy it. Thanks!